# Using a single crud model for all controllers instead of separate models for each controller

Tags: php, oop, crud

so i've seen ususally a model is representation of a table in database like for users table it goes something like :

```
class user_model {

  public $id ; 
  public $username ; 
  public $password ; 
  public $email ;


  public function save(){
     $db->query(" insert into `users` (username , email , password ) values ( '$this->username' , '$this->email' , '$this->password' ) ");
  }

  public function delete(  ){
     $db->query(" delete  from users where id = $this->id   ");
  }

}
```

but this proccess is pretty slow and what most of models do is basic CRUD operation ... so i use a single crud model for almost all of my controllers like :

```
class crud_model {

  public function save( $tbl ,  $data ){
     $db->query(" insert into $tbl  ( ".explode( ',' , array_keys($data) )." ) values ( ".explode( ',' , $data )." ) ");
  }

  public function delete(  $tbl ,  $data ){
     $db->query(" delete  from $tbl  where $data['column'] = $data['val'] ");
  }

}
```

*pleas note this is a very simplified version of my model and basically its nothing like the original code ( im using active record in the original code and it can handle complex scenarios ) so ignore syntax and technical errors*

so i want to know if there is a problem with this approach ? am i missing something ?

**whats the point of having lots of models when you can get by with one CRUD model .... it just seems like wast of time**

Comment: Despite the fact that you should be using prepared statements to obtain security gain, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos actually im using active record for the query ,  i just wanted to keep the code as simple as possible

Comment: Instead of using a single class, you could inherit a common base class in order to write the `save` and `delete` methods only once.

Comment: @user3409662 good idea , but basically most models contain the same CRUD methods so im going to save some time by not creating them in the first place

Comment: Whats wrong with a good MVC Framework? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I would also think about extending from a base class with the CRUD methods. I've taken similar approaches before. The SQL can still be dynamic based on table/column definitions in the child classes, but I wonder if it's going to far by making things so generic. It's fine for simple cases like above, but as soon as any complexity creeps into the SQL/models things get tricky.

Comment: @Stony i am using a mvc framework (CI) , i just want to know if it's ok to use it like this

Comment: @Drumbeg i've been using this crud model for a year now and its matured enough to handle complex cases with ease that's not a issue

Comment: @Drumbeg about extending its a great idea , but thats the whole point ... i dont need anything but CRUD in 99% my models and i dont want to waste time and slowing down the project  by creating models that are not really necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not necessarily *wrong*.  As programmers, we like things to be consistent so that when you have to make modifications to your code you don't need to worry about one table model working differently from another table model.  We're also lazy (in a good way) so that you want to be able to write your CRUD class once and use it everywhere.  You've got that part down with your single class idea.

However, if you take your CRUD class and then have all of your table models inherit from it you get the benefits of having written the code once, plus if you need to do something with a table that falls outside of your base CRUD code you can easily override or add to the functionality in your child table class.

In terms of the **pattern** of having a model to represent your tables, with your current approach, you can't truly represent individual tables with a generic CRUD class.  Model classes will often have additional class properties that are specific to the table being represented.  This allows you to design your classes so that if they were to be re-used, the developer has a better understanding of the underlying data structure.  Look at your example of the `User` class in your original question.  That class has properties such as `$id`, `$username` and `$password`.  A developer can look at that and know exactly what is needed to create a new User.